# Single Card Element not Updated in the Flatlist React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, flatlist

I want to update my list when the picker change then the itemName also change with the picker Value but it is not Happening can someone Explain me Why?

```
Chat Screen

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Pressable,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

import { AutoGrowingTextInput } from "react-native-autogrow-textinput";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import backgroundbot from "../assets/backgroundbot.png";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Card } from "react-native-shadow-cards";

import { setQuery, selectPicker } from "../store/Slices/ChatScreenSlice";


const ChatScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectedData = useSelector((state) => state.ChatScreenSlice.selectedData);
  const query = useSelector((state) => state.ChatScreenSlice.queryString);
  const selectedValue = useSelector((state) => state.ChatScreenSlice.selectedValue);
  const itemSelected = useSelector((state) => state.ChatScreenSlice.itemSelected);

  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(false);

  if (opacity === true) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOpacity(false);
      dispatch(setQuery(""));
    }, 5000);
  }

  console.log(selectedValue + "this is new render");


  return (
    <View style={style.chatContainer}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={style.imageContainer}
        source={backgroundbot}
        resizeMode="contain"
      >
        <View style={style.chatContainerResponse}>
          <AutoGrowingTextInput
            style={opacity ? style.textInputBoxUpOpacity : style.textInputBoxUp}
            editable={false}
            value={`Searching For ${query} Please wait....`}
          />

          <FlatList
            style={style.listStyle}
            data={selectedData}
            keyExtractor={(itemValue, key) => key}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={(item) => {


 
              return (
                <Card style={style.chatContainerResponse}>
                  <View style={style.responseContainer}>
                    <View style={style.container}>

                      <View style={style.container1}>
                        <Text style={style.containerText1}>Customer Number</Text>
                        <Text style={style.containerText2}>{item.item.customer_no}</Text>
                        <Text style={style.containerText1}>Item Name</Text>
                        <Text style={[style.containerText2, style.remarks]}>{item.item.item_name}</Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={style.container2}>
                        <Text style={style.containerText1}>Quantity</Text>
                        <Text style={[style.containerText2, style.remarks]}>{item.item.quantity}</Text>
                        <Text style={style.containerText1}>Customer Name</Text>
                        <Text style={[style.containerText2, style.remarks]}>{item.item.customer_name}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>

                    {item.item.context_required && (<View style={style.pickerContainer}>
                      <Text style={style.PickerWarningText}>Please Specify! {Object.keys(item.item.context_required)}</Text>
                      <Text style={style.PickerWarningText}>Selected {selectedValue}</Text>

                      <Picker
                        selectedValue={selectedValue}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {

                          dispatch(selectPicker({
                            type: 'SELECT_PICKER',
                            index: item.item.id,
                            itemValue: itemValue,

                          }));
                        }}
                      >

                        <Picker.Item label="Select a Value" value="Select a Value" />

                        {item.item.context_required.item_names ? (item.item.context_required.item_names.map((val, index) => {
                          return <Picker.Item key={index} label={val} value={val} />

                        })) :
                          (item.item.context_required.customer_name.map((val, index) => {
                            return <Picker.Item key={index} label={val} value={val} />
                          }))}
                             
                      </Picker>
  

                    </View>)}

                  </View>
                </Card>
              );
            }
            }
          />



        </View>

        <View style={style.textInputField}>
          <View style={style.textInput}>
            <AutoGrowingTextInput
              style={style.textInputBoxDown}
              placeholder="Enter Your Sale Order Query..."
              onChangeText={(itemValue) => dispatch(setQuery(itemValue))}
              editable={opacity ? false : true}
              value={query}
            />
          </View>

          <Pressable onPress={() => setOpacity(true)}>
            <View style={style.buttonContainer}>
              <Feather
                style={style.button}
                name="send"
                size={24}
                color="black"
              />
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>

  );
};

export default ChatScreen;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  chatContainer: {
    flex: 10,
  },

  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,

  },

  responseScreen: {
    flex: 10,
  },

  responseContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 1,
  },

  textInputField: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 40,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },

  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  chatContainerResponse: {
    flex: 9,
    marginHorizontal: 1,
    marginVertical: 2,
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },

  textInputBoxUp: {
    margin: 1,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: 17,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    opacity: 0,
  },

  textInputBoxUpOpacity: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: 17,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    opacity: 1,
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },

  button: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },

  textInputBoxDown: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 30,
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: 20,
  },


  //Response Container Styling

  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },


  container1: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },

  container2: {
    marginLeft: 20,
  },

  containerText1: {
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 1,
  },

  containerText2: {
    fontWeight: "300",
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 25,

  },

  remarks: {
    width: 150,
    padding: 'auto',
  },


  //picker styling

  pickerContainer: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    width: '40%',

  },

  PickerWarningText: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 16,

  },
});
```

Chat Screen Slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const ChatScreenSlice = createSlice({


  name: "ChatScreenSlice",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    selectedData: [],
    queryString: "",
    selectedValue: "",
    itemSelected: false,
  },

  reducers: {

    setData: (state, action) => {
      const data = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...data],
        selectedData: [...data],

      }

    },

    setQuery: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        queryString: action.payload,
      };
    },

    selectPicker: (state, action) => {

      const { index, itemValue, type } = action.payload;

      const data = state.selectedData.find((item) => item.id == index)
      if (data) {
        let tempObj = state.selectedData.map((item) => {
          if (item.id === index) {

            for (var key in item.context_required) {
              if (key == 'item_names') {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  context_required: { item_names: [itemValue] },
                  item_name: itemValue,
                  selectedValue: itemValue
                }
              }
              else {
                return {
                  ...item
                }
              }
            }

          }

        })


        return {
          ...state,
          selectedData: [...state.selectedData, tempObj],
        }

       
      }
    },










  },
});

export const setData = ChatScreenSlice.actions.setData;
export const setQuery = ChatScreenSlice.actions.setQuery;
export const selectPicker = ChatScreenSlice.actions.selectPicker;
export default ChatScreenSlice.reducer;
```

Here is Data

```
const Data = [
  {
    id : 1,
    context_required: {
      item_names: ["PARIS Guest Chair", "LONDON Swivel Chair"],
    },
    customer_name: "The Cannon Group PLC",
    customer_no: "10000",
    item_name: "Chair",
    quantity: 10.0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "The Cannon Group PLC",
    customer_no: "10000",
    item_name: "AMSTERDAM Lamp",
    quantity: 3.0,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "Selangorian Ltd.",
    customer_no: "20000",
    item_name: "AMSTERDAM Lamp",
    quantity: 3.23,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "Selangorian Ltd.",
    customer_no: "20000",
    item_name: "LONDON Swivel Chair",
    quantity: 1.0,
  },
  { 
    id: 5,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "The Cannon Group PLC",
    customer_no: "10000",
    item_name: "LONDON Swivel Chair",
    quantity: 10.0
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    context_required: {
      customer_name: ["The Cannon Group PLC", "Selangorian Ltd."]
    },
    customer_name: "customer",
    customer_no: "10000",
    item_name: "AMSTERDAM Lamp",
    quantity: 3.0
  },
  {
    id :7,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "Selangorian Ltd.",
    customer_no: "20000",
    item_name: "AMSTERDAM Lamp",
    quantity: 3.23
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    context_required: null,
    customer_name: "Selangorian Ltd.",
    customer_no: "20000",
    item_name: "LONDON Swivel Chair",
    quantity: 1.0
  }
];

export default Data;
```

Please Somone Explain me How to change the Picker Value in Flat list and the Item Name and Picker Change its Value same time. I am Trying to do this by Manipulating my state which contain the complete data but is show me my list and in last it show some other card without Values Why??